# Can anyone tell me whats wrong with this mysqli login code?

Tags: php, mysqli

I am making a login using mysqli and i keep getting these errors.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/TmUAw.png

```
<?php
class Database {
  public function __construct() {
    $host = 'localhost';
    $user = 'root';
    $pass = 'login';
    $name = 'meeboo1';
    $this->mysqli = new mysqli($this->host, $this->user, $this->pass, $this->name);
  }
}
?>
```

Can someone please tell me what i am doing wrong? I thought they were already declared?

Comment: What are the difference between `$user` and `$this->user`? One of them is a local variable, the other a property. And the former exists, while the latter doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

You should try accessing variables defined inside you function like this:

```
$this->mysqli = new mysqli($host, $user, $pass, $name);
```